# sqrt being defined multiple places (xtgmath)

Tags: c++, c++11, resharper, std, cmath

I include the c+ header `<cmath>`, rather than math.h and expect a function like `sqrt` to then be defined in std as `std::sqrt`, but to my surprise resharper kept insisting that `std` was redundant in writing `std::sqrt`

After some digging, it turns out that there is a `sqrt` in the global namespace and after digging even more, it comes from including `<vector>` which in turn includes `xtgmath.h` which defines `sqrt` in the global namespace.

Vector being a modern header (as in not named .h), this is a bit surprising to me.

I guess, apart from the annoying resharper notification, it doesn't really matter, since I can still explicitly write `std::sqrt` and be sure which I get, but then again, I could forget the std somewhere and effectively randomly be using a different implementation, which seems a bit off to me.

Am I seeing problems where none are?
What is the proper way to deal with this?

Comment: I imagine you're familiar with *why* this is happening, but for those interested, there would be some further reading about [ODR](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) and [inline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline)

Comment: C++ implementations are permitted to declare names from the C library in both the global namespace and namespace `std` via `using` declarations, and some do.